# Connecting to EC2 Instance via Terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I am completely new to coding and am doing a startup course on coursera: https://class.coursera.org/startup-001/lecture/87

I'm getting a Permission Denied (publickey) when trying to connect to an EC2 Ubuntu Instance I created on AWS

1. Set up AWS Istance
2. Set Security to default and added port 22 and launched
3. Course tells me to then type:

   chmod 400 trevor-learning.pem
   ssh -i trevor-learning.pem \ ec2-user@ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

This then gives me this error: Permission denied (publickey).

I've looked at other questions asked and tried switching the ubuntu@ to ec2-user and some other things but I still can't connect.

I also tried: 
    trevor-larsons-macbook-pro:downloads trev$ chmod 600 trevor-learning.pem
    trevor-larsons-macbook-pro:downloads trev$ ssh -v -i trevor-learning ubuntu@ec2-XX-XXX-XX-    XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

which gave me:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
Warning: Identity file trevor-learning not accessible: No such file or directory.
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [XX.XXX.XX.XX] port     22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/trev/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/trev/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/trev/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/trev/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
debug1: Host 'ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/trev/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/trev/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/trev/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

At a loss here and have NO idea what I am doing please help!

Also, not sure if this has anythign to do with it, when I download the instance certificate (shows up bottom left of chrome browser, it opens up my keychain access and says" an error has occured. unable to import an item. the contents of this item cannot be retrieved."

Comment: The error you need to pay attention to is this: `Warning: Identity file trevor-learning not accessible: No such file or directory.`

Comment: @datasage I don't understand really what i'm doing. The file is in my downloads folder. I go to the directory in my terminal then do the rest from there. it eventually asks: The authenticity of host 'ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (XX.XXX.XX.XXX)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 2f:71:6a:82:4d:ec:29:a2:eb:12:96:f3:09:17:71:e1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com,XX.XXX.XX.XX' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following steps in your terminal:

```
ssh-keygen -R 12.345.678.999 // This Reset your publickey
```

Then try to access with your **Key Pair Name** and **Public DNS** of EC2:

```
ssh -i KeyPairName.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Woohoo thank you so much!! to be honest, taking out the "\" between the KeyPairName and ubuntu@ is what did the trick, not sure why but thank you!!

Comment: the \ character is often used to indicate a continuing line when notating a long command that has to wrap to the next line due to width constraints (ie, if printed in a book or an online tutorial). It is not meant to be typed out, but in general, if you copy and paste it into your terminal, the terminal will ignore it and execute the command correctly. See a better explanation at this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash#Usage)